# How to achieve a curve with css

Tags: css

I need to achieve a curve as the one in the picture. Any ideas on how I could achieve using just CSS?

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

[image]

**What I tried:**

```css
.box {
   width: 500px; 
   height: 100px;  
   border: solid 5px #000;
   border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
   border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Property `clip-path` does the trick. It works (similar) as svg's. Building elements with `clip-path` needs a little learning. Here is a good report about how to use:

https://ishadeed.com/article/clip-path/

But be careful when using in a project. The property is only partly supported by the browsers:

https://caniuse.com/?search=clip-path

So you need to test ... or use a svg.
That is a common supported feature.